# Automatically deactivate Redshift when playing videos in fullscreen

Tags: video, fullscreen, color-management

I'm using [Redshift](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/redshift) to adjust color temperature according to the position of the sun. When I start to play videos in fullscreen I want it to (automatically) be deactivated, and I want it to (automatically) be reactivated when I stop watch videos in fullscreen. Can this be done? If so, how? Ideally I want it to work with any player, e.g. with Totem and with VLC.

Comment: The author of this question hasn't been seen in over a year, and this question has lows views. If anyone has a similar problem I suggest that they [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). Thanks!